# Why my makefile fails, when I replace g++ with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, makefile

I am coding in OS X
   Here is my Makefile:

```
#makefile for stack_5_1
# Yitong Zhou

stack_5 : main.o Stack.o LIFO_Stack.o Peekback_Stack.o
    g++ -o stack_5 main.o Stack.o LIFO_Stack.o Peekback_Stack.o
main.o: main.cpp Stack.h LIFO_Stack.h Peekback_Stack.h
    g++ -c main.cpp
Stack.o: Stack.cpp Stack.h
    g++ -c Stack.cpp
LIFO_Stack.o: LIFO_Stack.cpp LIFO_Stack.h
    g++ -c LIFO_Stack.cpp
Peekback_Stack.o: Peekback_Stack.cpp Peekback_Stack.h
    g++ -c Peekback_Stack.cpp

clean: 
    rm -rf *.o stack_5
```

The error:

```
.....  // very very long 
Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in Stack.o
Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in LIFO_Stack.o
Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in Peekback_Stack.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [stack_5] Error 1
```

What is the difference between gcc and g++? Why does my compile fail when I replace g++ with gcc?

By the way, how could I ensure that my makefile could be run correctly in Cygwin, linux, OS X and maybe other environment.

Comment: Concerning your "btw", why not simply write another question? My *first* suggestion in such a case: name the file `GNUmakefile` if you run on an environment where you potentially clash with other incarnations of `make` (other than GNU make).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc is for compiling C by default

g++ is for compiling C++ by default

The primary difference is that g++ transparently adds the options `-x c++` (use C++) and `-lstdc++` (use C++ standard library).

Try this Makefile:

```
stack_5: main.o Stack.o LIFO_Stack.o Peekback_Stack.o

main.o: main.cpp Stack.h LIFO_Stack.h Peekback_Stack.h

Stack.o: Stack.cpp Stack.h

LIFO_Stack.o: LIFO_Stack.cpp LIFO_Stack.h

Peekback_Stack.o: Peekback_Stack.cpp Peekback_Stack.h
```

make will automatically fill in the sensible rules based on the file extensions.

Also take a look at the `-MM` gcc option.  It will automatically generate the correct make dependencies (which header files) so you don't need to maintain this list manually.  There is more in the make manual and gcc manual about how to use it.

Comment: So if I just simply write g++, will it work all correctly in different UNIX environments?

Comment: Well if you are using make you should use the default macros for the C++ compiler.  See the make manual for a list.

Comment: Andrew refers to this list: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html ... in particular `$(CXX)` (for C++) as opposed to `$(CC)` (for C)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I kinda get the difference between this two compliers. So do you think it is a good practice to always use g++ or gcc while building c++ files?

Comment: Depends entirely on your needs. It is, however, always good practice to use the `CXX` variable for C++ and override it where and whenever needed.

Comment: Actually make has implicit rules so you shouldn't even need to enter any build commands.  Just specify the dependencies and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` as a linker, IIRC, doesn't link in standard `c++` libraries, like `-lstdc++`. Not sure if it's enough to make sure everything works on all systems, you may need to use autotools or similar.

Answer (score 0):

gcc is meant to compile plain C while g++ accepts (compatible) C and C++ code.

That's probably the reason for your errors.